# In an array of int's, how can I return the index corresponding to the lowest value?

Tags: java

I've managed to find the lowest value in the array with my "lowest" variable, but im looking for the index which corresponds to the lowest value in the array. Any ideas?

```java
public class Marathon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = { "Elena", "Thomas", "Hamilton", "Suzie", "Phil", 
                           "Matt", "Alex", "Emma", "John", "James", "Jane",
                           "Emily", "Daniel", "Neda", "Aaron", "Kate" };

        int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445, 402, 388, 275, 243, 334, 
                        412, 393, 299, 343, 317, 265 };

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + times[i]);
        }
        lowesttime(names, times);
    }

    public static void lowesttime(String names[], int times[]) {
        int lowest;

        lowest = times[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < times.length; i++) {
            if (times[i] < lowest) {
                lowest = times[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lowest);

        // to access arrays names[?], times[?}
        // System.out.println(names[lowest] + ": " + times[lowest]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i` is the index

Comment: Keep the track of lowest index just the same as you are doing for `lowest` like `lowestIndex = i`.

Comment: You can save the `i` along lowest so you will have the index!

Comment: It's recommended to place the brackets behind the type instead of behind the variable name, e.g. `String[] names` instead of `String names[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to the index of the element, instead of just getting the value of that element;

```
public static void lowesttime(String[] names, int[] times) {
    int lowest;
    int lowestIndex = 0;

    lowest = times[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < times.length; i++) {
        if (times[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = times[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(lowest);
    System.out.println(lowestIndex);

    // to access arrays names[?], times[?}
    // System.out.println(names[lowest] + ": " + times[lowest]);

}
```

Comment: `lowestIndex` should be initialized to 0

Comment: To add on to what michalk said, if it is not initialized your `print` will be an error.  Without the print, the variable will be a warning.

Comment: And also `for (int i = 1; i < times.length; i++) {}` this loop will skip last element of array. Loop should start with `0` or end when `i<=times.length;`.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha Where does it skip the last element?  `i` was declared as `1` because the _first_ value is set to `lowest` _before_ the loop.  It goes into the last element just fine, `i <= times.length` will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void lowesttime(String[] names, int[] times) {
    Pair<Integer, Integer> min = IntStream.range(0, times.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Pair<Integer, Integer>(i, times[i]))
            .reduce(new Pair<>(-1, Integer.MAX_VALUE), (r, p) ->
                r.getKey() == -1 || r.getValue() > p.getValue() ? p : r);

    String minName = p.getKey() == -1 ? "nobody" : names[p.getKey()];
    System.out.printf("Found minimum for %s at index %d, value %d%n",
        minName, min.getKey(), min.getValue());
}
```

I wanted to show using a Stream:

- `IntStream.range(0, N)` will give a stream of 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1. The indices.
- `mapToObj` converts to a `Stream<Pair<Integer, Integer>>` where the pairs key is the index, and the pairs value is `times[index]`.
- `reduce` will start with an initial pair (-1, Integer.MAX_VALUE) as result,
  and then for every pair in the stream whether a better minimum can be found.

Note you could just use a pair of name and time (`Pair<String, Integer>`); the index is not needed.

It here might be too advanced and circumstantial, but it is both very *expressive* and *clean* (using steps without needing local variables).

Answer (score 0):

If you already know your lowest value, you can use:

`java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray).indexOf(lowestValue)`

Comment: This is technically correct but since you are iterating the array to find the lowest value, you end up doing an entire extra iteration to get the index of the value. It won't matter on small arrays, but on large ones it is a waste of time.